# How to display current value into Textfield

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-hook-form

I want to display default value for my Textfield. In this case I want to create the form when users will can update their profile but I need to display current data like name. Look at this simple example:

```
const ProfileSettings = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(10);
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: name,
    },
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("get-profile").then((data) => {
      setName(data.data.name);
    }, []);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        id="name"
        defaultValue={name}
        label="name"
        type="string"
        variant="outlined"
        {...register("name")}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

In this simple example Textfield display 10 (value from backend = 200). Value in useState id updated but it doesn't updated value in TextField.

How can I update values in my form from backed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value to your TextField

```
 <TextField
    id="name"
    value={name} // here
    defaultValue={name}
    label="name"
    type="string"
    variant="outlined"
    {...register("name")}
  />
```

See also the [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/) for TextField

Answer (score 0):

can you try this..

```
const ProfileSettings = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: name,
    },
  });
  useEffect(() => {
      getProfile();
    }, []);
  });
  
  const getProfile = async ()=>{
    axios.get("get-profile").then((data) => {
      setName(data.data.name);
    });
  }  


  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        id="name"
        defaultValue={name || ''}
        label="name"
        type="string"
        variant="outlined"
        {...register("name")}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```